# Vercel Rewrite: SPA Fallback except for API endpoint

Tags: vercel

I have a single page application + API I'm deploying to Vercel.

I'm currently trying to add some configuration in my vercel.json that:

1. redirects calls not at the root (e.g. `/login) to` index.html` so that I can utilize the HTML History API (i.e. react-router's browser router)
2. expect not for the `/api` endpoint where I have a few dynamic paths (e.g. `/files/[fileId]/[checksum].ts`)

How do I create a rewrite in Vercel that accomplishes this?

I've followed the advice from here: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#routes/advanced/spa-fallback

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

However this does redirects API endpoints with dynamic paths to the index.html file too where I just want this to be the API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) that check the url doesn't contains `api`.

```
/(?!api\/.*).*/
```

```json
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/((?!api\/.*).*)",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how do you create this route if you are using a custom root directoy folder ( like "src" ? ) thanks

Comment: sorry, I having trouble understanding your question. you ask what if the backend is on custom directory, is that correct?

Comment: So, I have my api folder under "./src/api". Since my serverless fn are under "./src", I defined the vercel project rood directory as "./src". In case, it is not clear for me how I should be creating the rewrites routes :-7

Comment: @AlbertoS. You stil could make the root is /, so then you create api/myapi.js that just import to your src/api/myapi.js. but you have to make "link" each routes. instead, you could use router library, and just have single entry, and then rewrites all api to that single entry (for example: api/index.js to src/api/index.js with api/* rewrites to api/index.js). because vercel is kind of not working if the api is on other directory. perhaps there is configuration for that. but me myself is using this method.